# Transpose per batches of 24RX56C in excel to columns of 56 rowsX24c

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I need to make a transposition of 24RX56C to 56RX24C in excel for more than 144000 data points. I need to do this transposition per batch. So far I have been working with the VBA platform and macros to record a code that allows doing for the whole data set but still is not working. I think it is because of the "active cell.Offset" that keeps varying. therefore when I want to use "Do until isempty(activecell) and loop. the code takes different values and not the batches that I want it to take.
I would appreciate any suggestions. I am attaching the code I have been using and also a pic of how I want to make the transposition.

```
Sub TRANSPOSE()
'
' TRANSPOSE Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
    Range("A1:E2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(6, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(9, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-7, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(12, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-10, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(15, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-13, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(18, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Load it into an array and then reverse the order when you output it. Something like this should do the trick

```
Sub transpose_it()
  arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
   For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Sheet2.Cells(i, j) = arr(j, i)
  Next j
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!. is this a VBA code? I just tried and it is not working.

Comment: "It's not working" is rather unhelpful. Can you be more specific? How did you test? What's the result you got?

Comment: hey @Claudia, it does work. I would recommend learning more about vba arrays and how to load and unload them. google "vba mastery arrays" that should point you in the right direction

Comment: thank you for your answers! @JoshPachner, when I tried the code the message of " run-time error'424': object required appears. I click debug and it points to Sheet2.Cells(i, j) = arr(j, i).

Comment: thank you @variatus the code works but not quite well, when I select the batch in                                               
    Const DataSource    As String = "A2:E5" (for instance) it moves the data from sheet1 to sheet 2 in the same format( no transposition). However when I select just one column in                                         
 Const DataSource    As String = "A2:A5"the code makes the appropriate transposition. but still the code does not reach the objective to transpose the data per batches

Comment: @Claudia, not sure why that is happening. Granted I was just doing a more simple one. what Variatus has written looks like it is more complex and can do more of what you need. Remember though that the code here isn't necessarily to solve your problem but gives the tools that others along the way will be able to pick from and solve their problems. Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is VBA code. It must be installed in a standard code module. That is a module that doesn't naturally exist in your workbook. It must be created. It's default name will be `Module1` but I recommend that you give it a meaningful name (can't include spaces). After the code is installed the workbook must be saved as "macro enabled" with a xlsm extension.

```
Sub ReorderDataPoints()

    ' specify the range of your data batch here
    Const DataSource    As String = "A2:D3"
    Const OutputTab     As String = "Sheet2"        ' change as appropriate
    
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    Dim Arr             As Variant          ' array: input data
    Dim C               As Long             ' loop counter: input columns
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: input rows
    Dim Out             As Variant          ' array: output data
    Dim i               As Long             ' loop counter: output row
    Dim j               As Long             ' loop counter: output columns
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' change as appropriate
    Arr = Ws.Range(DataSource)
    ReDim Out(1 To UBound(Arr, 2), 1 To UBound(Arr))
    i = 1
    
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            j = j + 1
             If j > UBound(Out, 2) Then
                j = 1
                i = i + 1
            End If
            Out(i, j) = Arr(R, C)
        Next C
    Next R
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ws = Worksheets(OutputTab)
    If Err Then
        Set Ws = Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = OutputTab
    Else
        Ws.Cells.ClearContents              ' delete existing data
    End If
    Ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Out), UBound(Out, 2)).Value = Out
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before you run the code set its parameters. There are two constants at the top you will need to assign values to. One specifies where the data to be converted are, the other where you want the output to be. You must also look for the code line `Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")` and change the worksheet's name. This is the sheet on which your original data are, and the code expects it to be in the same workbook as the code.

For a quick guide to the procedure's action, the code reads the data from the specified batch range (can be any part of the worksheet, with any number of rows and columns), sorts the data into a pattern to reverses the number of rows and columns, and then write the result to another worksheet. If that worksheet didn't exist at the start it will be created. If it did exist all data in it will be deleted irretrievably without warning. The target sheet will be active when the code is done.